# OrientDB 2.2.13 console.sh: getting "Cannot create a connection to remote server address(es)"

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have an embedded database where I start an OServer and trying to connect to it from the console. I've been doing this successfully for many months and upgrading the database as new versions come out. Now, with 2.2.13, the embedded operations seem to work but I can't connect to the server with the 2.2.13 console.sh. I get the message:

```
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot create a connection to remote server address(es): [127.0.0.1:2424]
DB name="master"
```

The java code running the embedded database gets the following exception:

```
    $ANSI{green {db=db}} Error executing request
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on plugin lookup: the server did not start correctly
    DB name="db"
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.getPlugin(OServer.java:850)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.openDatabase(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:857)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.handshakeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:229)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.execute(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:194)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)
```

Seems to be looking for the 'cluster' plugin.

Any idea why this doesn't work anymore? It did work in 2.2.12.

Thanks

Curtis

Comment: If it worked fine on 2.2.12, could be a bug, you can submit it on github

Answer (score 1):

Seems I had automatic backup turned on but the config file was missing. So, the server looked like it started up but actually didn't.

I created the config file and set enabled to false. Still didn't start up because it sees the false and stops the configuration and throws an exception because the 'delay' parameter isn't set.

I think orientdb should start up without backups enabled if the config file is missing or the enabled parameter is set to false.

At least the console is working now.